# Is it possible to add a grid or table in my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, images, tables

Is it possible to add a grid or table in my profile?
I want to make my profile look like the snap shot below. When I click on a logo, it'll navigate to a link.

[image]

Comment: `<img><img><br><img><img>`? Why does it need to be in a table?

Comment: @animuson let me try

Comment: @animuson It's not working. but i solved it by `<br/><br/>`

Comment: @animuson thnx for giving me this trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it just by `<img><img><br/><br/><img><img>`

## Output is:

[image]